# display tags in jtable

Tags: java, jquery-jtable

I'm using the Jtable and java spring MVC in my project and it's very good. But I have a problem when display the data. In my data, there is a field Title with contain is : "< Team > 49ers < / Team >". But in jtable, I receive : "49ers". < Team > and < / Team > are gone. How could I can display "< Team >"and "< / Team >" in jtable ?

Comment: is the tag `jquery-jtable` correct? show some code.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a JTable issue. It works fine for me:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;

public class SSCCE extends JPanel
{
    public SSCCE()
    {
        JTable table = new JTable(5, 5);
        table.setValueAt("<Team > 49ers < / Team >", 0, 0);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane( table );
        add( scrollPane );
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("SSCCE");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add( new SSCCE() );
        frame.setLocationByPlatform( true );
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Add a System.out.println(...) to wee what data is returned from the database.